# onActivityResult not being invoked from startActivityForResult (C++ Builder 11.2)

Tags: java, android, delphi, firemonkey, c++builder

I am creating an Android app in C++Builder, which installs an APK and then restarts the app that was installed.

I am able to do both on our tablet (trucking application) individually.  However, since the install requires user confirmation, this may take a while.  The problem is that I want the `Intent` to complete with a result before I start the application.

Below is the main code, which invokes the APK install `Intent` and the method `onActivityResult()` which allows me to get out of the `while` loop.  However, I never actually get out of the `while` loop.

I have seen Delphi code that will override `onActivityResult()`, but I can't seem to get C++Builder to allow me to override the member function.

Please excuse the multiple commented out code, they were approaches I tried but did not work, either.  I left the `messageManager` code in also, but the message handler never gets invoked, either.

```cpp
void __fastcall TForm5::Button3Tap(TObject *Sender, const TPointF &Point)
{
    //GetDirs();     Works, so comment out for now to concentrate on intent function
    UnicodeString filePath = 
       "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.embarcadero.Immixt/files/Download/Immixt.apk";

    if (TFile::Exists(filePath)) {

        _di_JContext Context = TAndroidHelper::Context;

        // Create the intent to install the APK file
        // Set the path to the APK file in the app's data directory
        _di_JString ApkFilePath = StringToJString(filePath);
        UnicodeString mimeType = "application/vnd.android.package-archive";
        _di_JString mimeType1 = StringToJString(mimeType);

        // Create the intent to install the APK file
        intent = TJIntent::JavaClass->init();
        intent->setAction(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);

        //intent->setAction(TJIntent::JavaClass->ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE);
        intent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent->putExtra(TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
        intent->putExtra(TJIntent::JavaClass->EXTRA_RETURN_RESULT, true);

        _di_Jnet_Uri Uri1;
        _di_JFile APKFile = TJFile::JavaClass->init(ApkFilePath);
        try {
           Uri1 = TAndroidHelper::JFileToJURI(APKFile);
        } catch (const Exception& e) {
            //CLog::d(TAG, e);
            _di_Jnet_Uri Uri1 = TJnet_Uri::JavaClass->parse(ApkFilePath);
        }

        //_di_Jnet_Uri Uri1 = TJnet_Uri::JavaClass->parse(ApkFilePath);
        intent->setDataAndType(Uri1, mimeType1);

        // Start the activity to install the APK file
        activityResult = -1;
        //Context->startActivity(intent);
        FMessageSubscriptionID = TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), HandleActivityMessage);
        //TAndroidHelper::OnActivityResult = &onActivityResult;
        //TAndroidHelper::Activity->startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        SharedActivity()->startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);

        /*
        TAndroidHelper::Activity->startActivityForResult(intent, 1234,
        [this](int requestCode, int resultCode, _di_JIntent data)
        {
            Form5->onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        });
        */

        while (activityResult == -1)
        {
            Sleep(100);
        }
        // Wait for the activity to complete
    }

/---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

void onActivityResult(int i, int i1, Androidapi::Jni::Graphicscontentviewtext::_di_JIntent intent)
{
    TMessageManager::DefaultManager->Unsubscribe(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), Form5->FMessageSubscriptionID);
    Form5->FMessageSubscriptionID = 0;

    // For more info see https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent
    if (i == 1234)
    {
        if (i1 == TJActivity::JavaClass->RESULT_OK)
        {
            Form5->activityResult =0;
        }
        else if (i1 == TJActivity::JavaClass->RESULT_CANCELED)
        {
            Form5->activityResult =0;
        }
    }
}
```

I am expecting the following code to wait until `activityResult` is changed to exit the `while` loop.  `activityResult` is modified in the `onActivityResult` event, which should be called by `SharedActivity()->startActivityForResult(intent, 1234)` according to all the documentation.  But it never does.

Comment: On a side note: if `TAndroidHelper::JFileToJURI()` raises an exception, your `catch` block is assigning the result of `TJnet_Uri::JavaClass->parse()` to the wrong `Uri1` variable.

Comment: Thank you.  Did not see this earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you don't get the events. Your `while` loop is blocking the main UI thread from processing new messages.

Get rid of the `while` loop altogether, it doesn't belong in this code. `Intent`s are **asynchronous**, they are meant to run in the background while you move on to other things.  So, you should exit from `Button3Tap()` entirely (disable your UI if you need to), and then let the RTL call your registered callback at a later time when it is ready to do so, at which time you can then continue on with your work (and re-enable your UI) as needed.

For example:

```
void __fastcall TForm5::Button3Tap(TObject *Sender,
    const TPointF &Point)
{
    ...
    // Start the activity to install the APK file
    FMessageSubscriptionID = TMessageManager::DefaultManager->SubscribeToMessage(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), HandleActivityMessage);
    SharedActivity()->startActivityForResult(intent, 1234);

    // disable UI if needed...
    // exit here
}

void __fastcall TForm5::HandleActivityMessage(System::TObject* const Sender,
    System::Messaging::TMessageBase* const M)
{
    TMessageResultNotification* notif = dynamic_cast<TMessageResultNotification*>(M);
    if (!notify)
        return;

    if (notify->RequestCode == 1234)
    {
        TMessageManager::DefaultManager->Unsubscribe(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), FMessageSubscriptionID);
        FMessageSubscriptionID = 0;

        // use notify->Value and notify->ResultCode as needed...

        // re-enable UI if needed...
    }
}
```

Comment: Remy, thank you for the quick response.  I implemented your answer and even though the HandleActivityMessage is invoked now with the notify->RequestCode returning with '1234', the notify->ResultCode is '0'.  The prompt for the user to install the apk is still displayed when the member is invoked.  Once the user presses the install, the message is never handled again.  Here is the code I used (to setbreak points) it seems its invoked once the intent is launched, but I need it to know once the intent is complete.  Or when the install is complete if possible.

Comment: 'void __fastcall TForm5::HandleActivityMessage(System::TObject* const Sender, 
   System::Messaging::TMessageBase* const M)
   {
 TMessageResultNotification* notify = dynamic_cast<TMessageResultNotification*>(M);
 if (!notify)
  return;

 if (notify->RequestCode == 1234 && notify->ResultCode !=0)
 {

  TMessageManager::DefaultManager->Unsubscribe(__classid(TMessageResultNotification), FMessageSubscriptionID);
  FMessageSubscriptionID = 0;

  // use notify->Value and notify->ResultCode as needed...

  // re-enable UI if needed...
  Button3->Enabled = true;
 }
}
/*'

Comment: You are using `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` on your install `Intent`, so you are getting a result from the act of launching the new task, not a result from the task itself. The Android documentation [clearly states](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK): "*This flag [FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK] can not be used when the caller is requesting a result from the activity being launched*", which is exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: That was it.   Just remove   //intent->addFlags(TJIntent::JavaClass->FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); and presto!  Thank you, remote download working.

Comment: This is also covered in the [`startActivityForResult()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)) doc: "*Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that are defined to return a result. In other protocols (such as `Intent#ACTION_MAIN` or `Intent#ACTION_VIEW`), you may not get the result when you expect. **For example, if the activity you are launching uses `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` , it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result**.*"

Comment: Thank you, Remy.  I think I tried the onActivityResult prior to the HandleActivityMessage without the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK originally (so many efforts and easy to forget).  Based all the forum posts I then tried to override it like in Delphi with no effect.  I will go back and try again since I believe it is the preferred method.  Definitely appreciate the ‘intent’ references since I will be using it for IPC between apps.

Comment: Just FYI for anyone interested, I am developing on version 9.  I think ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALLED and PackageManager have to be used for anything 11 and above since ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE is deprecated.